# Took a Sales Position worked 3 days sold 2 waterproof jobs

Tags: salary

The Company is 100% legit ...problem is I didn't fill out any paper work and my commission from the 2 jobs total $1400. I know it sounds crazy but this job isn't for me because the owner has bad business ethics and I don't want to be tied to it after thinking twice about it.

I've known the guy for 20 years. When I told him the job is not for me and why it wasn't, he got all upset and said I wasted his time and said a lot of low blows.

I got a down payment of $2k cash. I am worried that I'll never get paid after I turn it in. Tomorrow is literally the 7th day if I make it that long with his company. He repeatedly keeps texting saying he's going to report it as theft. I  plan on turning it unless told else wise because that;s never been my style.  However I only acknowledged I would turn in his ipad and lazors. I know I'm about to get pimped. What should I do?

I have texts that are harassing and I repeatedly told him to come to my house. He refuses and wants me to go to his house. I'm worried that it might get hostile.

Comment: So to be clear - the company gave you $2000, which you are now supposed to give back to them, and you are owned $1400 for the work you did for them.  You think that you'll turn in the $2000, and they won't give you the $1400?

Comment: The easy answer to that is to return $600. Plus, presumably, the company equipment. Either of you going to the other's house in the circumstances is a bit weird and has the potential to turn tricky legally; could you not agree to courier the company property back to the office?

Comment: If you cannot agree on courier, meet at a safe neutral location. First agree on exactly what will be handed over. Some police stations have designated spaces for that sort of transaction.

Comment: What do you mean 'no paperwork'? No paperwork for the sales? Or no employment paperwork? Currently you seem more dodgy than the boss since you're holding money that isn't yours. Unsure how this construes as bad business ethics on the bosses part and not yours. So you need to clarify.

Comment: Can you clarify what a "down payment" is in regard to your job?

Answer (score 6):

> What should I do?

Give your notice and leave. Ignore all harassing texts and requests to go to his house. Make it clear that your decision is final.

Return whatever is due, then deal with any remaining issues as they come up.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?
>
> I have texts that are harassing and I repeatedly told him to come to my house. He refuses and wants me to go to his house. I'm worried that it might get hostile.

Keep all communications and records you have to this point, to defend yourself against false claims.

If you meet, make sure it's in a public place. Document as much as you can, whether that's through email, or recordings of conversations (if legal in your jurisdiction). Also bring someone with you if possible, and make sure someone else knows where you are, who can provide help.

Bring with you the company equipment, and only $600. There's no reason to give $2000 to get paid $1400. Don't bring additional cash or a blank check.